# Estou a fazer uma calculadora,porém quero que o programa pergunte ao usuário se ele quer usar denovo,se quiser o programa continua a rodar

Tags: python-3.x

Aqui está meu código:

```
def add(x, y):
  return x + y

def subtract (x, y):
  return x - y

def multiply (x, y):
  return x * y

def divide (x, y):
  return x / y

print('Select operator.')
print('1.add')
print('2.subtract')
print('3.multiply')
print('4.divide')

escolha = input(' (1/2/3/4) \n')
num1 = float(input('1º número: '))
num2 = float(input('2º número: '))

if escolha == '1':
  print(num1, '+', num2,'=', add(num1,num2))

elif escolha == '2':
  print(num1, '-', num2,'=', subtract(num1,num2))

elif escolha == '3':
  print(num1, '*', num2,'=', multiply(num1,num2))

elif escolha == '4':
  print(num1, '/', num2,'=', divide(num1,num2))

else:
  print('Não é uma operação válida!')

answer = input('Sim ou não ')
u = input('.')
v = input('..')

if answer == u:
  print('Quer usar denovo?')

elif answer == v:
  print('continue...')
```

O que preciso mudar??

Answer (score 0):

Entrando a resposta for "s", ele vai continuar no loop do while

```
def add(x, y):
  return x + y

def subtract (x, y):
  return x - y

def multiply (x, y):
  return x * y

def divide (x, y):
  return x / y

while True:  

  print('Select operator.')
  print('1.add')
  print('2.subtract')
  print('3.multiply')
  print('4.divide')

  escolha = input(' (1/2/3/4) \n')
  num1 = float(input('1º número: '))
  num2 = float(input('2º número: '))

  if escolha == '1':
    print(num1, '+', num2,'=', add(num1,num2))

  elif escolha == '2':
    print(num1, '-', num2,'=', subtract(num1,num2))

  elif escolha == '3':
    print(num1, '*', num2,'=', multiply(num1,num2))

  elif escolha == '4':
    print(num1, '/', num2,'=', divide(num1,num2))

  else:
    print('Não é uma operação válida!')

  continuar = input('Outra operação? (s) \n')
  if continuar != 's':
    break;
```

Comment: e se a resposta for não?

Comment: @gui_1765 ai ele entra no if e o programa encerra...